# Как правильно разбить на слоги слово ОТЧИЗНА

Tags: фонетика, слоги

Увидел два варианта разбиения слова **отчизна** на слоги:

```
о - тчи - зна

от-чи́з-на
```

Какой из них верный?

Answer (score 4):

Слог определяется как произносительный квант речи. Он не выражает смысловых связей звуков, как морфемы,  а  характеризуется АКУСТИЧЕСКОЙ ИЛИ АРТИКУЛЯЦИОННОЙ слитностью звуков при их произношении.

По одной теории (артикуляционной), слог – это один гласный звук или несколько звуков, которые произносятся ОДНИМ ТОЛЧКОМ выдыхаемого воздуха (лод-ка).

По другой теории (акустической), слоги строятся по принципу ВОСХОДЯЩЕЙ ЗВУЧНОСТИ (ло-дка).

Получается: 1) от- чиз -на,  2) о - тчи -зна.

Мне первая теория кажется более естественной, она больше подходит для школьной практики.

Вторая теория, как мне кажется, в большей степени историческая, она ориентирована на исторический период до падения редуцированных гласных, когда слоги были открытыми.

Answer (score 2):

В русском языке закрытым (заканчиваться на согласную) может только последний слог, во всех остальных случаях слог всегда открытый, даже если там огромное скопление согласных (*му-дрству-ет*). Соответственно, в вашем случае правильным разделением на слоги будет первый вариант - **о-тчи-зна**.

Более подробно о делении на слоги можете прочитать по [ССЫЛКЕ](http://www.licey.net/russian/phonetics/1_6).

Comment: Всё верно. При переносе слово разбить нужно так: отчи-зна.

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: от-чи́з-на. Т.к. по правилам не разрешается оставлять на строке или переносить в следующую строку одну букву. Напр., нельзя переносить: а-кация, акаци-я.

См.: Академический справочник.

Comment: Вы не на тот вопрос ответили. Спрашивают о разделении на слоги, а не о правилах переноса. Причём даже в правилах переноса неточность. Правильно - *от-чи-з-на*.